# Problema com Spring Tools Suite

Tags: java, linux, spring-boot, jdk, spring-tools-suite

Estou iniciando meus estudos com Spring e baixei o Spring Tool Suite versão 3.9.4. para desenvolver aplicações java web. Eu já havia instalado previamente o JDK versão 8. Estou usando o Ubuntu 18.04. 
**Dadas estas informações, vamos ao problema:**

Ao tentar iniciar uma aplicação Spring Starter project, o menu não apresenta as opções de início, retornando o erro: "InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty"

[image: Erro]

Ao buscar este erro no Google, vi que pode ser milhares de coisas, mas nada específico ao STS ou mesmo ao Eclipse, porém sei que está ligado a algum problema com uma lib do Java. Eu vi uma solução no Stackoverflow em inglês, para realizar o comando "sudo /var/lib/dpkg/info/ca-certificates-java.postinst configure", ele atualizou mas não resolveu o problema. Se alguém tiver alguma sugestão, agradeço!

Comment: tentou esse comando aqui: `update-ca-certificates -f` ?

Comment: Tentei agora, mas não deu certo também.

Comment: Tenta baixar o projeto desse link e importar no eclipse http://start.spring.io/

Comment: Não consegui importar o projeto, fui até procurar no youtube para ver se eu estava fazendo algo errado, mas o projeto nem aparece para importar. Segui o caminho File>Import>General>Existing Projects into Workspace (depois de descompactar o arquivo zipado) e ele não aparece no campo projects. @WeslleyBarbosa.

Comment: Esta errado, os projetos spring vc deve importar eles como Maven, Maven> Exist Maven Project

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, mas desisti de usar o STS no linux. Como uso o windows em dual boot, quando for necessário utilizarei por lá e continuarei meus estudos de linux com outras ferramentas.